# Comparing  two rows within two separate tables

Tags: php, mysql, comparison

I have two tables in a database one named *purchases* and one named *items*.

My problem is i'm trying to process whether an item listed in the purchases can be returned.

For instance, **Person A** purchases Item A, and B. Both purchases are inserted into the *Purchases* table. Item A, and B are listed in the *Items* database aswell. *Items* contains whether it is returnable or not. What is the most efficient way to check both what items the person has purchased and is returnable?

Thanks!

Comment: You leave us guessing a lot - having the exact set of columns for each tables (or at least the relevant ones) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, you'll want to do the following:

```
SELECT item_id, can_be_returned
FROM Purchases P
JOIN Items USING (item_id)
WHERE purchase_id = 42
```

So you'll get the items - whether they can be returned - from the purchase which ID is 42.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from purchases p
inner join items i on p.id = i.purchase_id
where p.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for query something like this

```
mysql_query("select col1.purchases,col2.purchases,col1.items where somecol.purchase=somecol.items");
```